# Web API 2 Scaffolded controller's routing vs empty controller's routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

As you know Visual Studio provides scaffolding for MVC and Web API controllers. In my case I'm using Entity Framework along with Web API 2.

When I add a new web api 2 controller with actions using Entity Framework, Visual Studio pretty much creates a controller with 5 endpoints.

One of these endpoints is to retrieve a single record from the database.

Here is an example for that:

```
// GET: api/Courses/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Course))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCourse(int id)
{
    Course course = await _db.Courses.FindAsync(id);
    if (course == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(course);
}
```

The above controller works fine if I call it as api/Courses/5, but it also works fine if I call it as api/Courses?id=5.

My question is, if I add an empty Web API 2 controller, define these methods manually along with some other endpoints, I can either call the endpoint like the first call or the second call, but not both.

Is there a way to set up routing of an endpoint which would accept both options?

PS: I know how to separately set up routing for each of above options. My question is whether it is possible to set up for both.

Comment: I need to add a route attribute if I define it manually since this is not the only Get method in the controller. I will look into `IHttpControllerSelector` though.

Comment: Err, see `ApiControllerActionSelector` instead